# My selenium program isn't able to click on an input box

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, sendkeys

I have made a program to grab a youtube link and type it on a website but its not able to find the input box...plz tell me why

```py
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    import pyautogui as auto
    
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=closer+8d'
    web = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
    web.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    link = web.find_element_by_id('video-title')
    link = link.get_attribute('href')
    auto.hotkey('ctrl', 't')
    auto.typewrite('https://www.youtubemp3.pro/en2')
    auto.press('enter')
    time.sleep(3)
    search_bar = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="videoURL"]')
    search_bar.click()
    search_bar.send_keys(link)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\pranil\python\doing shit with python\songs downloader.py", line 17, in <module>
    search_bar = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="videoURL"]')
  File "C:\Users\Pranil.DESKTOP-TLQKP4G.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Pranil.DESKTOP-TLQKP4G.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Pranil.DESKTOP-TLQKP4G.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Pranil.DESKTOP-TLQKP4G.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="videoURL"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath you provided to find an element doesn't seem to work ""//[@id="videoURL"]"" I also opened up a YouTube video to see what you were looking for but I couldn't find videoURL if you are trying to get the URL I recommend you have selenium click on the share button and grab the link from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui as auto

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=closer+8d'
web = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
web.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
link = web.find_element_by_id('video-title')
link = link.get_attribute('href')

web.execute_script("window.open('https://www.youtubemp3.pro/en2', 'new_window')")
web.switch_to_window(web.window_handles[-1])
ylink = web.find_element_by_id("videoURL")
ylink.click()
ylink.send_keys(link)
submit = web.find_element_by_name("submitForm")
submit.click()
```

you do not have to use pyautogui it will work better if you use seleniu

Answer (score 0):

try to find the element with it's ID.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=closer+8d'
web = webdriver.Chrome('../assets/chromedriver')
web.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
link = web.find_element_by_id('video-title')
link = link.get_attribute('href')
web.get('https://www.youtubemp3.pro/en2/')
time.sleep(3)
search_bar = web.find_element_by_id('txt-url')
search_bar.click()
search_bar.send_keys(link)
```